# GeoMap data as per OData API- SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana, web-ide

I could successfully load location data (lat,lon) at my Dashboard UI in tabular form  using Odata API. Now I need to display them in a Map. I'm referring [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.vbm.sample.AnalyticMapSpots/preview) as sample. Here is images of my dashboard [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFfhm.png) . Now from my table, I only need to display the location of the first row data in my map. please help on how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [One-Step GeoMap Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/vbm/bestpractices.html)
it should be possible, to use any image for a spot.
In section “Resource Handling for Visual Objects” it says:
In addition to the semantically-typed Spot with a built-in visualization, you can use any image for a Spot. 
The image needs to be loaded as a resource and can be referenced by Spots.
Since the Spot was built for images like pins, the image is, by default, aligned in a way that the bottom center of the image is at the given geo position. 
For other images, a center alignment might be more appropriate.

Here is the code for JavaScript Views in UI5:

```
var oVBI = new sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap({
   resources     : [
      new sap.ui.vbm.Resource({ "name" : "SAP_logo",
                                "src"  : "images/SAP_logo.png"}) 
   ],
   vos : [ new sap.ui.vbm.Spots({
      items : [ new sap.ui.vbm.Spot({ position : "20;0;0",
                                      tooltip  : 'SAP',
                                      image    : "SAP_logo",
                                      scale    : "0.2;0.2;0.2",
                                      alignment: "0"}) 
      ]
   })]
});
```

Comment: Maybe i can find here https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/iconExplorer.html, but the url is not working today for some reason.

Comment: i used this `<vbm:resources>
     <vbm:Resource name="truck.jpg"
      src="images/truck.jpg">
     </vbm:Resource>
 </vbm:resources>
 <vbm:legend>
     <vbm:Legend id="legend" caption="Legend">
      
      <vbm:LegendItem text="Hari- Mumbai" image="truck.jpg" />
     
     </vbm:Legend>
    </vbm:legend>`